# Generic List and corresponding method

Tags: c#, list, generics

sI am pretty noob in generic Lists and would really use some help. (Don't even know if generic is the apropriate use for my cause).

I have :

```
 public class GenericList<T> : IList<T>
    {          
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public int state { get; set; }            
    }
```

All I want is to create a method that will take as an argument the state of `T` and will return its `firstIndex`.

I guess it is pretty simple but as I mentioned no experience with so ever

Comment: What do you mean by "the state of T"? Do you mean you want to search for an item?

Comment: T doesn't have a state, T is any type of object. Your genericList has a state though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you don't need your class `GenericList` at all since there is already a generic `List<T>`. Maybe you want to create a class `State`:

```
public class State
{
     public DateTime date { get; set; }
     public int state { get; set; }       
}
```

So you want to find the index of the first with a given state, you can use [`List.FindIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var allStates = new List<State>();
// fill ...
int index = allStates.FindIndex(s => s.state == givenState);
```

If you don't have a list(but an array or another kind of `IEnumerable<State>)` you could still get the index with LINQ:

```
int index = allStates.Select((s, index) => new { s, index })
    .Where(x => x.s.state == givenState)
    .Select(x => x.index)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(-1)
    .First();
```

Comment: Thanks, thats what excatly wanted, but I didnt even know how to address it correctly

Answer (score 2):

If you want to search the list for an index you don't need to create a specific subclass of `IList<T>`, you can use the built-in methods for that. Here's an example:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int State {get; set;}
    public DateTime Date{get; set;}
}

public void somemethod()
{
    var list = new List<SomeClass>();
    list.Add(new SomeClass{State = 5});

    // Get all the items with state 5
    var itemsWithStateFive = list.Where(item => item.State == 5); 

    // Find the first index of an item that has state 5
    var indexOfStateFive = list.FindIndex(item => item.State == 5); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you want to use some of T properties/methods inside your class. To do this you can set an interface requirement to T.

```
interface IMyInterface{
    int GetState();
}

public class GenericList<T> : List<T> where T: IMyInterface 
{          
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public int GetState(int i){return this[i].GetState(); }
}
```

Like this. But elements of your list will have to implement `IMyInterface`.